# database copy shell script including password with special characters

Tags: bash, shell, passwords, mysql

I am trying to create a shell script for a `mysqldump` (and `mysql`) operation where the password is stored directly in the script. The password contains special characters which need to be handled accordingly. However, I cannot figure out a combination that actually works.

For example, the following works when executed *directly* on the console:

```
mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password=the\$password | mysql -u the_user target_db --password=the\$password
```

The password contains a `$` which is then escaped with `\$`. However, the exact same command does not work when put into a `shell_script.sh`. When I execute the script, MySQL complains

```
Access denied for user 'the_user'@'localhost'
```

So far I have tried the following within the script:

```
mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password=the\$password | mysql -u the_user target_db --password=the\$password

mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password="the\$password" | mysql -u the_user target_db --password="the\$password"

mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password='the\$password' | mysql -u the_user target_db --password='the\$password'

mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password="the$password" | mysql -u the_user target_db --password="the$password"

mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password='the$password' | mysql -u the_user target_db --password='the$password'
```

None of these seem to escape the password properly. Out of these, only the first one works properly when used directly on the shell.

What am I missing? How do I have to specify the password, so these commands also work from within a shell script?

Comment: Is the actual problematic character a dollar sign?

Comment: The actual password also contains other special characters, like `%`, `=`, `?`, `#` for example. However, out of these I only need to escape the `\$` - at least directly on the shell. The `%` is at the beginning of the password, if that makes any difference (which it might?).

Comment: `%` isn't special at all. `?` might cause problems, though, as it might try to match. Whitespace could also be a problem. Backslashing every problematic character should work, though.

Comment: Still no luck. I have backslashed every character outside of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and still the command does not work when executed via a script. It still only works when executed directly on the command line.

Comment: Are you sure there's no `ssh` or other additional level of interpretation involved in the script?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Aside from an `echo` command before and after the mentioned command, there is nothing else in the `.sh` file.

Comment: Try running the script with `set -xv` to see how the string gets interpreted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :). However it seems I even need help to implement _that_ … when I put `set -xv` as the first line in my script, I only get 
`: invalid option_staging.sh: line 1: set: -`
`set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]`

Comment: Does the script run in bash?

Comment: By default it does, yes. If I run it via `sh` I get `shell_script.sh: 1: set: Illegal option -`.

Comment: The error is weird. Do you have MSWin line ending after `set -xv`?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. I am editing the file directly on the Linux machine via `vi`. There I should see any errorneous MSWin line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the password (without New Line and Without Escape) into a textfile e.g. `pass.txt` and then use the following

```
mysqldump -u the_user --hex-blob --add-drop-table source_db --password=$(cat pass.txt) | mysql -u the_user target_db --password=$(cat pass.txt)
```

Comment: That did not work. I am assuming by "without NR" you mean without escaping the characters?

Comment: without escaping and without the new lines.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. However `echo pass.txt` doesn't actually echo the contents of `pass.txt`... it just echos `pass.txt` ;)

Comment: Have you tried `cat pass.txt`?

Comment: yes, should be `cat pass.txt`. My mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
printf -v password "%q" "\$password"
mysql --password=$password
```

More details on `printf`:
[printf on wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)

Comment: That did not (quite) work either. Also with your version of the `mysql` part of the command (without the `=` between `--password` and `$password`), I simply end up in the `mysql` interface.

Comment: Actually the lack of `=` was a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much. However, it still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the password to the SQL ini file in a separate `[mysqldump]` section. If you need it for the MYSQL call too add it to the `[mysql]` section of the ini file also.

```
[mysqldump]
password="the$password"

[mysql]
password="the$password"
```